# Using Restangular and trying to set multiple parameters to a var from $scope

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, restangular

I am learning Angularjs and using Restangular to connect to Rails server API. I seem to be lacking a basic understanding of how to assign parameters from a form to a var that I will use in my function to post to my rails API.

Here is my controller (or the relevant portion):

```
.controller('NewCtrl', ["$scope", "Restangular", function($scope, Restangular) {

  var passages = Restangular.all('passages');
  var allPassages = passages.getList();

  var newPassage = {
    book: $scope.passages.book
  }; 

  $scope.add = function() {
    passages.post(newPassage);
  };
```

Here is my form:

```
<h1>Add New Passage</h1>
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="add()" ng-controller="NewCtrl" class="my-form">
  Book: <input name="passages.book" required><span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">Required!</span><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In the javascript console I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'book' of undefined
at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/main.js:38:27)
at invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3000:28)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3012:23)
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4981:24
at update (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14509:26)
at Object.Scope.$broadcast (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8468:28)
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7614:26
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6995:59)
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6995:59)
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7032:26
```

I think I am missing something in how I can assign values from my form with $scope to a value in my var. When I assign a literal value of say: book: "Ephesians" it works just fine. Thanks for help with this question.

Comment: You need to use ng-model directive on your input element: 'ng-model="passages.book"'.

Comment: OK. That is a good catch. I added the ng-model="passages.book to the input tag, but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to fix your controller:

```
.controller('NewCtrl', ["$scope", "Restangular", function($scope, Restangular) {

    var passages = Restangular.all('passages');
    var allPassages = passages.getList();

    // Initialise $scope.passage:
    $scope.passages = {
        book: null
    };

    $scope.add = function() {
        passages.post({
            book: $scope.passages.book
        });
    };
}])
```

and the markup:

```
<h1>Add New Passage</h1>
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="add()" ng-controller="NewCtrl" class="my-form">
  Book: <input ng-model="passages.book" name="passages.book" required><span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">Required!</span><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but it appears that the value of book is nil. Here is the output from the Rails server: Started POST "/passages.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-21 10:23:11 -0400
Processing by PassagesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"book"=>nil, "passage"=>{"book"=>nil}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "passages" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-08-21 14:23:11.748020"], ["updated_at", "2014-08-21 14:23:11.748020"]]
   (0.6ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered passages/show.json.jbuilder

Comment: this worked! One slight change to your code was required. Just needed to close the controller with "}]);" instead of "})" Thank you for your help.